# How to know if client is in sync with server in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to implement a feature where I want the user to see if all requests to the server have been handled, i.e. that the client is in sync with the server so that the user can be confident that all his changes are saved.

My idea was to override `Meteor.call` and keep a counter for each call and then when a reply/error is returned I decrease the counter. I will then on the client show a message saying "Synced" if the counter is zero otherwise I will show "Unsynced".

Basically my question is if there is any "built-in" feature in Meteor which already handles this, keeping track of outgoing Meteor calls, or if I should proceed as I have started?

This is what my code looks at this moment:

```
var originalMeteorCall =  Meteor.call;
var counter = 0;
Meteor.call = function() {
    if (this.isClient) {
        if (arguments && arguments.length > 1) {
            counter++;
            var returnFunc = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
            var newReturnFunc = function (err, result) {
                counter--;
                return returnFunc(err, result);
            }
            arguments[arguments.length - 1] = newReturnFunc;
        }
    }
    var result = originalMeteorCall.apply(this, arguments);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good approach for several reasons. (1) a Meteor.call() can return before the underlying data changes have propagated back to the client via DDP, (2) Other users or background jobs may change the db and that new state may not yet be reflected back on the client. (3) It's really hackish. Think about making the latency of your updates so small your users never have to worry about it.

Comment: What you are thinking can be done  smoothly in ReactJS. Just deal with state management. And the best part of ReactJS is it has an excellent integration with Meteor.